# SFMC strips out script tags in email

Tags: marketing-cloud

SFMC has rolled out a new feature of gmail annotation for promotion tab which requires an script to be added in email template. When i am trying to add that script to my email, SFMC strips out the script tag from email.

Link for gmail annotation for promotion tab https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview

Is there any other way of having script tag in emails. One way that i am aware of is to have the script in Data extension as a value and then retrieve that value from DE via ampscript. Is there any other workaround for this.

Comment: there is an idea you can upvote  https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000EBsYQAW

Comment: I've coded up an annotation using that same format in a custom email template and had no issues whatsoever. Are you building this using your own template or a stock SFMC one? Also, post your script and I can take a look.

Comment: Hi Jason, I am using a custom template.Below script m using <script type="application/ld+json">
[{"@context": "http://schema.org/","@type": "Organization","logo": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/googleg_48dp.png"
},{"@context": "http://schema.org/","@type": "EmailMessage","subjectLine": "Exciting offers"
},{"@context": "http://schema.org/","@type": "DiscountOffer","description": "20% off","discountCode": "PROMO"
},{"@context": "http://schema.org/","@type": "PromotionCard","image": "https://www.google.com/gmail-for-marketers/promo-tab/markup-tool/sample.png"
}]</script>